# Bootstrap column with sub grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginning to work with bootstrap and am working on my first website that uses it. I have an understanding of the components but am far from an expert. My issue is I want to know the best practice to having rows in a bootstrap column.  I Currently have the set up as below. [image: Example of website]

I have the green and black boxes completed as they are basic but what is the best practice to fill the left green column with the three boxes.  I would like them to be clickable icons and for the icons to span each 33% of the green column, thus filling the column to the on the left. What is the best way to active this, looking for the best practice for the current bootstrap methods.

Thank you,

Zack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is specific to bootstrap, but as long as you're using `col-*` for the green and black boxes, the boxes in the green sidebar can be divs with 33% height, or whatever values that work for you

Comment: Thank you, I cant believe I have overlooked this. So simple. I was over thinking the idea during my research. I will give you the answer when the timer runs out.